# sublime text 2 autocomplete stopped working

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

My sublime text 2 editor has suddenly stopped auto completing for me. I noticed this yesterday.

It appears to work for html, and css. However nothing works for PHP or JavaScript. Variables I've defined in SCSS don't work and text I've repeated in many places doesn't either.

This was all working fine a couple of days ago, and I've not installed any new plugins or *knowingly* changed any settings.

I've had a look at the default settings and user settings files, and can't see anything to suggest autocomplete has been turned off.

If I try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on text that I know would usually autocomplete, I just see the message 'No available completion' in the status bar;

[image]

Could I have accidentally used some keyboard shortcut to do this? I don't know where else to look to check whether anything has been turned off inadvertently...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the contents of your user preferences (`Preferences -> Settings-User`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having that problem minutes ago, all of a sudden, so I think the cause is the same.

I've removed the plugin CodeIntel and now it works again.
To remove a package hit `ctrl+shift+P` and type "remove", select `Package Control: Remove Package`, hit `enter` and select the package you want to remove.

Hope this was your case.

Comment: The plugin `TypeScript` also prevent me from using auto-complete feature when editing JavaScript files. Removing it instantly restore auto-complete of these files.

Comment: TypeScript was the culprit in my case as well. You can also disable plugins, don't need to necessarily remove them.

Answer (score 1):

To check what package may cause the issue open the Sublime Text console (`Ctrl+~`), scroll up to the top of the console window. and look for the error messages.

One by one error message:

- write down the package name on a paper;
- remove the package (`Ctrl-Shift-P`->type `packremov`->`Enter`->select the package->`Enter`);
- close & reopen Sublime Text;
- check if the autocomplete works;
- repeat for other errored packages;

Afterwards for your ST healthy behaviour sake you can re-install desired packages and fix the errors for each one. Still check the autocomplete works after each fix.

Comment: I no loner use ST, however this does sound like a good logical solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Application Reset]

I used the "CleanMyMac 3" program and went to the uninstall section and located Sublime Text. Instead of uninstalling it I chose "Application Reset" in the "Smart Selector."

Once I reopened Sublime again everything was back to normal once again. I think mine went wrong when I removed the CodeIntel Package. I hope this helps you and anyone else that has encountered this issue.